# Is there url I can upload to for attachment

Tags: attachment

I want to use the following plugin to upload image as attachments in salesforce.
It requires the url for form action. Is there already defined url for the Attachment object?

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 2):

There is no URL which allows for you to arbitrarily upload data into Salesforce.

That said, you may be able to use the blueimp interface to enhance the look of a standard `<apex:inputFile />` in a VF page. This would use the same underlying mechanism as a form post which takes place when you upload a file into a controller and then insert an `Attachment` object and store the uploaded binary data that way.

---

My blueimp / file upload backstory:

I planned to use the blueimp plugin to perform drag and drop upload using the REST API, primarily because I wanted drag and drop, and wanted to use the recently added REST API feature for uploading binary files of up to 500MB (where a normal [file upload limit is either 10MB or 38MB depending on the mechanism which you are using to perform the upload](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/collab_files_size_limits.htm)).

I ran into troubles initially when trying to upload binary data via the REST API from a VisualForce page through the salesforce proxy. This problem was alleviated in the Summer '13 release which exposed the REST API directly to the `visual.force.com` domain. No need for the proxy any longer. Big thanks to @metadaddy for the [blog post with this information](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html).

Related SFSE question: [Timeout error when posting blob data to the REST API from a VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/12664/)

Armed with that information, I was able to make a `POST` using an `XMLHttpRequest` to send the binary data to the REST API. However, there is a requirement that the first part of the multipart message *must* have a `content-type` of `application/json` or `application/xml` and also have a `content-disposition` of `form-data` and the second part carries the binary payload.

I was unable to use the browser's native form handling features, namely the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, to properly craft the payload for me. The closest I was able to get using the browser was a `content-type` of `text/plain` for the metadata part of the message, which was rejected as an invalid type.

I managed to get it working using the [HTML5 File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and crafting my own payload as a concatenated string but this pattern requires the entire file to be read into the browser before the upload begins. If you split the local file into small pieces rather than read the entire file into memory, Salesforce doesn't have the ability to reassemble the pieces on the server side. So, that pattern for handling large files is out too.

In short, I don't think using the REST API for large binary uploads via a VF page is ready for prime-time quite yet and I have not revisited using blueimp for drag and drop uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with native Salesforce. Tools like Web-To-Lead allow for form submission, but don't accept POST data for file uploads.

Typically attachment uploads from an external site need to be done via the official APIs, such as the REST, Enterprise or Partner APIs. These require some form of authentication to ensure you are allowed to access the Org.

Another alternative would be to create a Force.com Site and upload the attachment via that.

There might be some third party services that handle the authentication for you. I found [How to send file uploads (attachments) to Salesforce](http://blog.formstack.com/2010/how-to-send-file-uploads-attachments-to-salesforce/) after a quick search.