# Salesforce REST Call with SessionID

Tags: javascript, chrome

I've got a Chrome extension running while I'm signed in to Salesforce. I want to use my active SessionID from my session to query Opportunities using Javascript. I've tried passing the sessionID via Ajax but that is not working (getting 401 error).

Here's my code so far:

```
function processSessionID(sessionID) {
    console.log(sessionID);
    // Make the REST call here
}


chrome.cookies.getAll({
  "domain": "lightning.force.com", "name": "sid"
}, function(cookies) {
  for(i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    console.log(cookies[i].value);
    var sessionID = cookies[i].value;
    processSessionID(sessionID)
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**: The answer to my question is on the right track. ForceTK does access the API via Javascript - which is what I'm loooking to do. However, it's failing to resolve names on a chrome extension.

**How can I make a REST call with with the sessionID to return a list of opportunities?**

Answer (score 1):

Calling the REST API in javascript using [forcetk](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) is pretty straightforward in a `content` script:

```
function processSessionID(sessionID) {

    var client = new forcetk.Client();
    client.setSessionToken(sessionID);

    client.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity", function(response){
        // do something with response, response is a list of Opportunities in this case
    });         
}
```

Using it from a popup seems a little more involved. Firstly, I think you would need to use a content script to setup the forcetk client and interact with Salesforce. Then, from your popup, you'd have to use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate back and forth. For example, in your `popup.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getOpportunities"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.opps);
  });
});
```

Then, in your `content` script, add a listener:

```
var client = new forcetk.Client();
client.setSessionToken(sessionID);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method === 'getOpportunities') {
      client.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity',function(response) {
        sendResponse({opps: response});
      }
    }
  });
```

PS. I haven't tried this but seems like it should work.

Comment: I do think OP needs a bit of direction on how to get the sessionId as well? Unless you usually look through cookies to figure that out?

Comment: It depends on what type of extension he's developing, but it can be as simple as `var sessionID = document.cookie.match("sid=([^;]*)")[1];`

Comment: Yes, chrome has a cookie api. Thx!

Comment: When I run this with the current sessionID I'm getting this; Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://okgglkjjoapejcmbmegeclmnfmdamool/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20Name%20FROM%20Opportunity&_=1474424357089. Looks like forcetk is not being passed the instance id. How do I do that?

Comment: What does this mean? ForceTK requires that you add the correct REST endpoint hostname for your instance (i.e. https://na1.salesforce.com/ or similar) as a remote site in Your Name > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Remote Site Settings.

Comment: After a lot of examination ForceTK does NOT work OOTB for chrome extensions. It's looking for hostnames and protocols (which are not typical from a chrome extension) attempts to proxy based on those variables.

Comment: Works in my chrome extension, maybe it depends on the type of extension. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/forcetk-in-a-chrome-extension-cross-domain-query-issue

Comment: Is your code being ran from a background script?

Comment: Phil - If you could post the link to a working example that would be great! Running on background or popup both fail for me as the url is coming back with chrome-extension://..... instead of https://na35.salesforce.com/...

Comment: My extension injects javascript into Salesforce pages so works exactly as quoted above. Take a look at @capeterson Grey Tab, that uses a popup with integration to Salesforce (https://github.com/capeterson/Grey-Tab)

Comment: Wouldn't the trick be to setup forcetk in your content script, and pass that to your popup using sendMessage or something?